# Invoke-RestMethod {"statusCode":400,"error":"Bad Request" } error

Tags: json, powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

```
$access_token ="secret"

$URI =  "https://oui.web.ser.ons"
$headers = @{“authorization” = “Bearer $access_token”} 

$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $URI -Headers $headers -ContentType $ContentType |ConvertTo-Json
$b = $Result|ConvertFrom-Json| Select -ExpandProperty audits

$Dates = $b | Foreach-Object {$_.modified_at = [DateTime]$_.modified_at; $_} | 
Group-Object Computer | 
Foreach-Object {$_.Group | Sort-Object $_.modified_at | Select-Object -Last 2}

$Audit_id = $Dates| Select audit_id | ft -hidetableheaders

$Audit_id= a_6d62b1f4d66c4a1a83c244469af93d3d
           a_0bf1e6b1a1c243539a9dbb241e920d0a
```

I am getting errors below using the script below: I am trying to loop the $Audit_id and get the JSON files.

```
$Audit_id= a_6d62b1f4d66c4a1a83c244469af93d3d
           a_0bf1e6b1a1c243539a9dbb241e920d0a


$uri = 'https://oui.web.ser'
$reportList = @(

    $Audit_id


)

$token = 'secret'
$headers = @{ Headers = @{ Authorization = "Bearer $token" }}

foreach ($report in $reportList) {
    Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "$uri/$report" @headers |ConvertTo-Json
```

But I am getting the error below. It seems it doesn't like the -Uri "$uri/$report" @headers line which contains "/".

[image]

Comment: The error code points to `$Audit_id` as the cause, are you able to remove remove a_0bf.... and added " around the first one, test this?

Comment: @Matthew. I need it to be in 
" https://oui.web.ser/a_0bf1e6b1a1c243539a9dbb241e920d0a " in order to call the API. Thanks

Comment: As @Matthew is saying, you are not defining your array correctly.  I assume `$Audit_id` is meant to be an array, which you can define like this: `$Audit_id = 'a_6d62b1f4d66c4a1a83c244469af93d3d', 'a_0bf1e6b1a1c243539a9dbb241e920d0a'`

Comment: @boxdog it is an array. I have edited my question to include how $Audit_Id is derived.

Comment: Yes, you go through a few steps to build it up, then over-write it with `$Audit_id= a_6d62b1f4d66c4a1a83c244469af93d3d 0bf1e6b1a1c243539a9dbb241e920d0a`, which throws an exception for me, so not sure if this is a typo or not, but it seems invalid.

Comment: The problem is "$reportList = @( $Audit_id " is causing the error. It doesn't like the $Audit_id but if I put a_0bf1e6b1a1c243539a9dbb241e920d0a it works.